# Line Equation with angle

Tags: math, geometry

How can I find equation of a line or draw a line, given a starting point, length of line and angle of line (relative to x-axis)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An equation of a line is like:

```
m*x + n = y
```

m can be calculated by angle; `m =  tan(angle)`
And if you know a start point then you can find n.

```
tan(angle) * startPoint_X + n = startPoint_Y
```

So `n = startPoint_Y - (tan ( angle) * startPoint_X )`

If you want to draw a line-segment and you know the length, the start point and the angle, there will be two equations.

The first is `m*x + n = y` (we solved it).

And this means `m*(endPoint_X) + n = endPoint_Y`

The second is to find the endPoint.

```
length^2 = (endPoint_X - startPoint_X)^2 + (endPoint_Y - startPoint_Y)^2
```

There are only two things that still we don't know: endPoint_x & endPoint_Y
If we rewrite the equation:

```
length^2 = (endPoint_X - startPoint_X)^2 + ( m*(endPoint_X) + n - startPoint_Y)^2
```

now we know everything except endPoint_X.
This equation will give us two solutions for endPoint_X. 
Then you can find two different ednPoint_Y.

Comment: Your second equation is wrong, it should be startPoint_Y - (tan ( angle) * startPoint_X ), but even then, the answer is far more complex than necessary.

Comment: i agree that this is more complex.
i just wanna show how to do it without trigonometric functions. 
i'd like not to use tan(), but i don't want to extend my answer more...:)
By the way, i edited. thanks...

Comment: Using sin and cos is much simpler.

Answer (score 43):

Starting point you know `(x1, x2)`, end point is `(x1 + l * cos(ang), y1 + l * sin(ang))` where `l` is the length and `ang` is the angle.

Comment: Should this not be written as:

Starting point you know ```(x1, y1)```...

Answer (score 24):

Let's call the start point `(x1, y1)` the other end of the line `(x2, y2)`.

Then if you are given a length [L] and an angle from the x-axis [a]:

```
x2 = x1 + (L * cos(a))

y2 = y1 + (L * sin(a))
```

If the angle is from the y-axis - swap the cos and the sin.

Draw your line from `(x1,y1)` to `(x2, y2)`.

You may find an ambiguity as to which direction you want the line to go,
you need to be careful how you define your angle.

Comment: Once I have the second point, and assuming the 3rd point connects to it to create a line at 90degs to the first point (corner of a rectangle) how do I adjust the angle to find the third point? and how can I find the frouth point, working backwards from the first? (I know the rectangles height and width)

Answer (score 6):

There is  actually two different questions: one in the title, another in the body.

Let's start by answering the question from the title:

**Line Equation**

The equation of a line is

```
y = a*x + b
```

where `a` is a tangent of an angle between a line and X-axis, and `b` is an elevation of the line drawn through (0, 0).

**Line equation given angle and a point**

You can easily calculate `a` (since you know angle), but you don't know `b`. But you also know `x0` and `y0`, so you can easily calculate `b`:

```
b = y0 - a*x0
```

Now, equation looks like this:

```
y = tan(fi)*x + y0 - tan(fi)*x0 = tan(fi)*(x - x0) + y0
```

**Draw a segment given point, angle, length**

We want to draw a segment from starting point so that it's length is L and angle to the x-axis is fi.

This is a totally different problem.

You should imagine a right-angled triangle whose acute angle positioned at (x0, y0).

You know Hypotenusa (L) and an angle (fi).

By definition,

```
a = L*cos(fi) (adjacent, x)
b = L*sin(fi) (opposite, y)
```

All you need is to add x0 and y0:

```
x1 = x0 + L*cos(fi)
y1 = y0 + L*sin(fi)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to draw it from `(0, 0)` to `(x_length, tan(angle)*x_length)`. The gradient will be `tan(angle)`. You can adjust this for a different starting point by subtracting everything from that starting point.

Comment: But the resulting line will not have length x_length.

Comment: This doesn't work for +- 90 degrees (+- pi/2 radians) and will have variable accuracy dependant on the angle (closer to +- 90 the more inaccurate).

Comment: if you're given a 'length along the x-axis' (in the original question), then you don't have a +/- case. that's also what `x_length` means. the question has since changed dramatically...

Comment: That is the answer to question from the title.

Answer (score 1):

To compute the line equation
from a point (x1, y1), and an arbitrary angle α we need to distinguish two cases:

1. If α is around k * pi/2 with k = +/-1, +/-2,... then the line equation is

   ```
   x =  my + b
   ```

   with

   ```
   m = cot(α)
   b = x1 - m * y1;
   ```
2. else the line equation is

   ```
   y =  mx + b
   ```

   with

   ```
   m = tan(α)
   b = y1 - m * x1
   ```