# I need to draw a triangle from a line segment - How do I find the center point?

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, geometry

In my javascript app, I have a line segment - basically, two known points on a canvas. I need to dynamically draw an obtuse isosceles triangle from those points where the largest line  is the two points and the two matching lines are from the center point to the edges.

So I guess the question is, how do I find the center point between any two given points?

[image]

I'm ok with javascript, not so much with the math. Every real world answer I could find for this question referred to a compass but I'm not sure how that translates to code? I'm ok drawing the lines, just not finding the point. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need at least one angle in order to achieve this.

Comment: First find the center point on the line segment (simple algebra), next find a perpendicular line to your original line that crosses that point (also simple algebra).  Pick any point on this line.  This will create your triangle.

Comment: @Hogan Not any point. OP specifically requires an obtuse isosceles triangle.

Comment: Note I just saw "OBTUSE" for this you need to make user the distance from the first point to the new point is less than 1/2 the original line.

Comment: @Zéychin - yeah I saw that and then before I could post the above I was called from my desk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this more simply, with just linear algebra and geometry

### Generate isosceles triangle

The point you are looking for is equidistant from both points you already have (that is what "isosceles" means). Thus it is on [the bisector (the line perpendicular to the segment and cutting it in two equal halves)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection#Line_segment_bisector) :

[image: drawing of obtuse isosceles triangle]
<sub>(source: [free.fr](http://fr.maths.free.fr/maths/mnr/quat-lec/drtesrem/image59.gif))</sub>

An orthogonal vector `u` to the segment [BC] is `( -(c.y-b.y), c.x-b.x )`, and thus all points of the form `A = I + t * u` with t any scalar (that is, a number), form with `B` and `C` an isosceles triangle.

To build this vector `u`, we take the direction of the [BC] segment, given by the vector from B to C, `(c.x-b.x, c.y-b.y)`, and we know that for any vector `(x,y)`, the vector `(-y,x)` is perpendicular to it : try the scalar product between them both.

The coordinates of `I` are trivial : the average (barycenter, really) of B and C `( (b.x + c.x)/2, (b.y + c.y)/2 )`

### Make 'em obtuse

In order for the angle to be obtuse, the distances `AB` and `AC` (which are the same) have to be smaller than the value for which the angle at A would be 90°.

**When the angle in A is 90°**, we have to look at the AIC triangle. Its angle in A is 90°/2=45° and since its angle in I is 90° and the sum of angles in a triangle is always 180°, AIC's angle in C is also 45°. Two equal angles is, like two equal sides, a characterization of isosceles triangles.

Thus, `AI = IC` and since `IC = BC / 2`, the limit value for `AI` is `BC / 2`.

**So now we have to choose a `t` such that `AI < BC / 2`**, where `AI = abs(t) * |u|`.

Let's remember that we did not take a normalized vector for `u`, so 
`|u| = sqrt( (-c.y+b.y)^2 + (c.x-b.x)^2 )`,
and we also have `BC = sqrt( (b.x-c.x)^2 + (c.y-b.y)^2 )`, thus `|u| = BC`.

So we can conclude that `abs(t) < BC / (2 * |u|) = 1/2`.

### Final algorithm : as simple as it gets

- Pick a `t` between `[-0.5,0]` or `[0,0.5]`, bounds excluded.
- `a.x = (b.x-c.x)/2 - t*(c.y-b.y)`
- `a.y = (b.y+c.y)/2 + t*(c.x-b.x)`

And last by not least, try it :

```js
function draw()
{
    var t = parseFloat(document.getElementById('t').value);
      
    a.x = (b.x+c.x)/2 - t*(c.y-b.y);
    a.y = (b.y+c.y)/2 + t* (c.x-b.x);

    // end of the math, do the drawing
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(a.x,a.y);
    ctx.lineTo(b.x,b.y);
    ctx.lineTo(c.x,c.y);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var b = {x:420, y:190}, c = {x:50, y:160}, a = {x:0, y:0};

ctx.fillRect(b.x,b.y,2,2);
ctx.fillRect(c.x,c.y,2,2);

document.getElementById('t').onchange = draw;
draw();
```

```html
<p>t=<input type="text" id ="t" value="0.2" /></p>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="300" />
```

Comment: Linear algebra makes understanding a bit more difficult, but the explanation and eventual simplicity of deriving `a.x` and `a.y` are great. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, this can all be done with basic algebra when working in 2D coordinates. You need to determine the center point and the slope of your original line and from those two pieces of information you can easily plot perpendicular points.

**Finding the center point**

To find the center point between two points you should be able to get the difference between the respective x and y coordinates and divide by two, then add it to the starting value:

```
function getCenterPoint(a, b) {
    return { x: (b.x - a.x) / 2 + a.x, y: (b.y - a.y) / 2 + a.y }; 
}

var p1 = { x: 10, y: 10 }
var p2 = { x: 90, y: 40 }
var center = getCenterPoint(pt1, pt2); // { x: 50, y: 25 }
```

**Finding the slope**

The slope of the line you can do the rise over run of it:

```
function getSlope(a, b) {
    return (b.y - a.y) / (b.x - a.x);
}

var slope = getSlope(p1, p2);
```

To get the perpendicular slope you can negate it and invert it:

```
var perpendicularSlope = -(1 / slope);
```

**Using the slope to plot points**

You can now plot any point on the line perpendicular to your center point. In your example, to go above your line you use an x value less than the center point, to go below your line you use an x value greater than your center point. To determine the y value you multiply the slope by your x value.

```
var pAbove = { x: center.x - 10, y: (center.x - 10) * perpendicularSlope };
var pBelow = { x: center.x + 10, y: (center.x + 10) * perpendicularSlope };
```

Comment: Now the perpendicular line... remember just invert the slope.

Comment: Sure, but come on... ;-) Help the questioner find one of the many third points on his obtuse isosceles triangle. That is his real question!

Comment: @markE - This helps, it is the first step of my algorithm

Comment: @Hogan I'm agreeing with you that a good answer requires more steps :-) My comment was actually trying to prompt musicfuel to more fully answer the question...

Comment: Thanks guys for all of your comments - this works and answers a couple of other questions I had as well! Thanks!

Comment: Upvote for nice answer! Just a note that if you go too far out on the tangent your isosceles triangle will become an acute triangle.

Comment: @markE, yes that is an issue. It is difficult to resolve that aspect without resorting to trigonometry. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571294/line-equation-with-angle for a good discussion on that.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the triangle is obtuse, if p1 and p2 are closer.