# How to calculate pixel coordinates having start (x,y) , length in pixel and angle?

Tags: python, math

I have an image 640 x 640 and I'd like to draw the line on it. Common task where package like PIL allows me to write a line using

`line(x1,y1,x2,y2)`

where x1,y1 is start the and x2,y2 is end line coordinates. I have a different task where I have x1,y1 and line length in pixels with angle of direction. How to calculate x2,y2 having those data only?
Thanks
Erick

As per stackoverflow.com Admins advice I'm modifying this comment instead of posting answer separately below to provide code to my question plus one doubt that this code works with 0 (zero) angle drawing straight line towards right hand site as it should however 90 degree angle looks like more 110 or something as per picture. What am I doing wrong ? Thanks again in advance.

```
import math
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def calc_x2y2(length, angle, x1,y1):
    x2 = x1 + math.cos(angle)*length
    y2 = y1 + math.sin(angle)*length
    return (x2,y2)

w, h = 640, 640
x1,y1 = w/2, h/2
shape = [(x1,y1), calc_x2y2(300,90,x1,y1)]
# creating new Image object
img = Image.new("RGB", (w, h),(225,225,225))
# create line on the image
img1 = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
img1.line(shape, fill="#401eba", width=5)
img.show()
```

[Straight line that should be 90 degree except it's not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taJoX.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line Equation with angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571294/line-equation-with-angle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a right angle triangle with given information. from there we can see that

`sin(A) = p/h cos(A) = b/h` --- (1)

Where `h` is length of line and `A` is angle `h` makes with `b(base)` and `p` is `perpendicular`.

We also know that

`X2  = X1+b and Y2 = Y1+p` --- (2)

Replacing p and b in (2) with (1) you will get

```
X2 = X1+cos(A)*h
Y2 = Y1+sin(A)*h
```

Answer (score 2):

sin(θ) is perpendicular/hypotenuse and cos(θ) is base/hypotenuse . So, this becomes a simple math's problem, where y2 = y1 + L.sin(θ) and x2 = x1 + L.cos(θ).
Hence, the new co-ordinates are:

`(y2 = y1 + L.sin(θ), x2 = x1 + L.cos(θ))`

where
L = length of line
θ = angle between line and X - axis

[image: See Diagram]

Comment: hi, why to you use L.sin(alpha) in your answer ? (just saw the answer and dont fully understand it ;))

Comment: yes, I understand the math and how you do it but the L.sin is strange do you mean with it L*sin() ? (I don't get the useage of the L)

Comment: Yes I mean L * sin (angle). I just got mixed into the Math.
Now, are you satisfied?

Comment: yep sorry just wnated to understand it

Comment: No problem, mate. Happy to help