# How to draw repeated slanted lines

Tags: python, opencv

I need to draw slanted lines like this programmatically using opencv-python, and it has to be similar in terms of the slant angle and the distance between the lines:

[image]

If using OpenCV `cv.line()` i need to supply the function with the line's start and endpoint. 
Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571294/line-equation-with-angle) StackOverflow accepted answer, I think I will be able to know those two points, but first I need to calculate the line equation itself.

So what I have done is first I calculate the slant angle of the line using the measure tool in ai (The actual image was given by the graphic designer as ai (adobe illustrator) file), and I got 67deg and I solve the gradient of the line. But the problem is I don't know how to get the horizontal spacing/distance between the lines. I needed that so i can supply the start.X. I used the illustrator, and try to measure the distance between the lines but how to map it to opencv coordinate?

Overall is my idea feasible? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Update 1:
I managed to draw this experimental image:
[image: slanted_lines]

And this is code:

```
def show_image_scaled(window_name,image,height,width):
    cv2.namedWindow(window_name,cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.resizeWindow(window_name,width,height)
    cv2.imshow(window_name,image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def slanted_lines_background():
    canvas = np.ones((200,300)) * 255
    end_x = 0
    start_y = 0
    m = 2.35
    end_x = 0
    for x in range(0,canvas.shape[1],10):
        start_x = x
        end_y = start_y + compute_length(m,start_x,start_y,end_x)
        cv2.line(canvas,(start_x,start_y),(end_x,end_y),(0,0,0),2)

    show_image_scaled("Slant",canvas,200,300)

def compute_length(m,start_x,start_y,end_x=0):
    c = start_y - (m * start_x)
    length_square = (end_x - start_x)**2 + ((m *end_x) + c - start_y) ** 2
    length = math.sqrt(length_square)
    return int(length)
```

Still working on to fill the left part of the rectangle

Comment: A simple option might be to draw the lines vertically on a slightly larger canvas, rotate the result 23 degrees clockwise and then crop.

Comment: or fill the pattern yourself. write the pixel touching loop in plain python, then use numba to JIT-compile. it'll be reasonably fast. -- you'd use a formula using `x` and `y` that assigns each pixel a brightness, and evaluate it for every pixel. that is very likely faster than drawing lines (if you want them to be anti-aliased anyway). -- let me know if you need an example of that.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz i updated my progress on the post, can you help me figuring out how to fill the pattern on the left part? Thank you!

Comment: @MarkSetchell very interesting idea! Thanks i will try this one too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code "shades" every pixel in a given image to produce your hatched pattern. Don't worry about the math. It's *mostly* correct. I've checked the edge cases for small and wide lines. The sampling isn't exactly correct but nobody's gonna notice anyway because the imperfection amounts to small fractions of a pixel. And I've used numba to make it fast.

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange
```

```py
@njit(parallel=True)
def hatch(im, angle=45, stride=10, dc=None):
    stride = float(stride)
    if dc is None:
        dc = stride * 0.5

    assert 0 <= dc <= stride

    stride2 = stride / 2
    dc2 = dc / 2
    angle = angle / 180 * np.pi
    c = np.cos(angle)
    s = np.sin(angle)

    (height, width) = im.shape[:2]
    for y in prange(height):
        for x in range(width):
            # distance to origin along normal
            dist_origin = c*x - s*y
            
            # distance to center of nearest line
            dist_center = stride2 - abs((dist_origin % stride) - stride2)
            
            # distance to edge of nearest line
            dist_edge = dist_center - dc2
            
            # shade pixel, with antialiasing
            # use edge-0.5 to edge+0.5 as "gradient" <=> 1-sized pixel straddles edge
            # for thick/thin lines, needs hairline handling
            # thin line -> gradient hits far edge of line / pixel may span both edges of line
            # thick line -> gradient hits edge of adjacent line / pixel may span adjacent line
  
            if dist_edge > 0.5: # background
                val = 0

            else: # pixel starts covering line
                val = 0.5 - dist_edge

                if dc < 1: # thin line, clipped to line width
                    val = min(val, dc)

                elif stride - dc < 1: # thick line, little background
                    val = max(val, 1 - (stride - dc))

            im[y,x] = val
```

```py
canvas = np.zeros((128, 512), 'f4')
hatch(canvas, angle=-23, stride=5, dc=2.5)

# mind the gamma mapping before imshow
```

[image]